# Array of Arrays sum in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
arry = [["a",3.0,3], ["b",4.0,4], ["c",5.0,5]]
```

I am looking for the following output

```
[["a", 3.0, [["b", 4.0, 7], ["c", 5.0, 8]]],
 ["b", 4.0, [["a", 3.0, 7], ["c", 5.0, 9]]],
 ["c", 5.0, [["a", 3.0, 8], ["b", 4.0, 9]]]]
```

This is what I have done

- With the size of the array, I iterated over the loop
- First, I have taken the first element.
- Deleted it and made a new array. I iterated
  through the new array, calculated the sum and pushed the elements to
  new array2
- I added the deleted element at the end

I am not able to produce the following above mentioned format of the output. The output I am able to do is

```
[a,3.0,b,4.0,7]
7 here is 3+4
[a,3.0,c,5.0,8]
[b,4.0,c,5.0,9]
..etc
```

Apart from that, how to code to display lets say only the elements less than 8

and get this output

```
[["a",3.0,["b",4.0,7]],["b",4.0,["a",5.0,7]],["c",5.0,[]]
```

Comment: What are the transformation rules (I don't see what your expected output means)?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Looks like a mapping between an element and every other element and when a specific element is the key their value is added to others.

Comment: Neither of your outputs are valid - you're missing some ] somewhere

Comment: I have changed the output and corrected the ]. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arry.map do |inner|
  dup = inner.dup
  n = dup[2]
  dup[2] = []

  arry.each do |other|
    next if other == inner # Only want other inner arrays
    other_dup = other.dup
    other_dup[2] += n
    dup[2] << other_dup
  end

  dup
end
```

This evaluates to:

```
[["a", 3.0, [["b", 4.0, 7], ["c", 5.0, 8]]],
 ["b", 4.0, [["a", 3.0, 7], ["c", 5.0, 9]]],
 ["c", 5.0, [["a", 3.0, 8], ["b", 4.0, 9]]]]
```

**Update:** Glad that's what you wanted.  This is ugly, but I think it satisfies your filtering goal:

```
mapped.map do |inner|
  inner_dup = inner.dup

  inner_dup[2] = inner_dup[2].select do |inner_inner|
    inner_inner[2] < 8  # Condition for the elements you want to test
  end

  inner_dup
end
```

This evaluates to:

```
[["a", 3.0, [["b", 4.0, 7]]], ["b", 4.0, [["a", 3.0, 7]]], ["c", 5.0, []]]
```

Note again that this is slightly different output than you specified, but I believe it's what you actually want. (What if more than one inner array matches per group?)

Comment: I changed the output in the question to reflect what I actually meant as well! Now coming to the second question how to display lets say only the elements less than 8?